# Confused in output of a program

Tags: c++, class

I'm new to c++ and i'm practicing about class. kindly someone help me with this. What's the error?

```
class Test1 { 
    int y; 
}; 

class Test2 { 
    int x; 
    Test1 t1; 
public: 
    operator Test1() { return t1; } 
    operator int() { return x; } 
}; 

void fun ( int x)  { }; 
void fun ( Test1 t ) { }; 

int main() { 
    Test2 t; 
    fun(t); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: That code has no output, so what are you confused about?

Comment: is output messages of the compiler probably, because `call of overloaded ‘fun(Test2&)’ is ambiguous`

Comment: you have ti realize difference between  compilation messages and "output" . Output is what program produces, not compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Compiler Error.
There are two conversion operators defined in the Test2 class. So Test2 objects can automatically be converted to both int and Test1. Therefore, the function call fun(t) is ambiguous as there are two functions void fun(int ) and void fun(Test1 ), compiler has no way to decide which function to call. In general, conversion operators must be overloaded carefully as they may lead to ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

When compiling :

> ```
> t.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
> t.cc:18:10: error: call of overloaded ‘fun(Test2&)’ is ambiguous
>     fun(t); 
>          ^
> t.cc:13:6: note: candidate: void fun(int)
> void fun ( int x)  { }
>      ^~~
> t.cc:14:6: note: candidate: void fun(Test1)
> void fun ( Test1 t ) { }
>       ^~~
> ```

To solve that you have to indicate your choice :

```
fun(static_cast<Test1>(t));
```

or

```
fun(static_cast<int>(t));
```

or of course to remove one of the conversion operator